# How i use react nested routing for my dashboard component

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, nested, react-router-dom

I am building an app that has 4 main pages and inside each, I have various components.

### Pages

1. Home
2. Dashboard

### Components

1. Home > (Services,About,Login)
2. Dashboard(Profile,ListUsers,SearchTweets ,etc etc...)

### Problems:

So home page components and its routing is perfectly fine.
The problem lies on the dashboard page. if I click on the profile component in the dashboard navbar on left side do not load component on right.Besides it redirect me to profile empty page(Images is attached)
[[1]][1]

### Code for dashboard

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from "react-router-dom"
import "./dashboard-style.css"
// protected for only authenticated or logged in users 
import NavDashboard from "../components/Navigation/dashboard-nav"
import Profile from "../components/Profile/profile"
function Dashboard() {
    return (
        <div className="outer-dash-container">
            <div className="left-dash-nav">
                <NavDashboard />
            </div>
            <div className="right-dash-panel">
                <h1>I want to show my componets here </h1>
                <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard
```

### Dashboard Navbar Code

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import "./navbar-style.css"
function NavDashboard() {
    return (
        <>

            <div className="nav-dash-left">
                <div className="logo">
                    {/* <h1><b className="text-format">Tox</b><i>D</i>etector</h1> */}
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li className="nav-link nav-link-dash"><Link to="/profile" className="nav-link"> Profile</Link></li>
                    <li className="nav-link nav-link-dash"><Link to="/block" ></Link>
                        List User
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-link nav-link-dash">Search Tweet</li>
                    <li className="nav-link nav-link-dash">Check Stat</li>
                    <li className="nav-link nav-link-dash"> Search By Cities</li>
                </ul>

            </div>


        </>
    )
}

export default NavDashboard
```

### This is my app routing

```
import './App.css';
import Register from "../src/components/User_Manage/register"
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import Login from './components/User_Manage/login';
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard"
function App() {

  return (
    <>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with the code you provided. I tried on codesandbox.io and it seems to work.

Comment: Try it yourself https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-proskuriakova-6wt47

Comment: I have also routing in app.js .Kindly check i also added my app.js in questions.May be this is problems there are two routings one in app.js and other one in dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove exact from the place in which you are nested routing it will work fine.